# RegEx: How to repeat pattern matched?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make sure that string matches rule that data matches following pattern

```
^\d{1,4}\,?
```

Basically it can be a list of numbers between 1-4 characters followed by ",". So this would be valid

1,12,123,1234 but 12345,123, would not. How does one tell it to repeat match? I tried grouping it and adding + at the end but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex should be using `$` also to make sure entire input is matched and use quantifier `+` for repetition:

```
var re = /^(\d{1,4}(,|$))+$/;
```

And use `RegExp.test` method to validate the input:

```
var valid = re.test(str);
```

**Testing:**

```
re.test('1,12,123,1234');
true
re.test('12345,123');
false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
/^(?:\d{1,4}(,|$))+$/
```